# Required assembly to get the prefix/keyword "sampleData" working for the Windows.Resources tag (telerik control)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, telerik

Here is the xaml

```
  <Window.Resources>
      <sampleData:RadTreeViewSampleData x:Key="someDataSource"/>
  </Window.Resources>
```

While i am following this tutorial for the link below i couldn't get the sampleData prefix to be picked up by the intellisense. Anyone have an idea which assembly should i reference to in order to make it work?

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtreeview-populating-with-data-data-binding-to-object.html

Comment: According to that linked page, *The sampleData alias points to the assembly where your data source is located*... that would mean the namespace of the `RadTreeViewSampleData` class that you created.

Comment: Thanks @Sheridian i am aware of that. the problem is when i use that tag i get the compliler message saying "the namespace sampleData is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an XML namespace for `sampleData` in your XAML file. In this XML namespace, you will need to use the (code) name space that you used in the `RadTreeViewSampleData` class that you added to your project. The XML namespace should look something like this:

```
xmlns:Attached="clr-namespace:Midas.Views.Attached;assembly=Midas.Views"
```

This particular example relates to the namespace used in the class that I want to use in XAML:

```
namespace Midas.Views.Attached // <<< This is the code namespace
{
    public class ListBoxProperties : DragDropProperties
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `assembly=Midas.Views` part of the XML namespace relates to the fact that the `ListBoxProperties` class is in a project named `Midas.Views`... if your `RadTreeViewSampleData` class is in your main project, then you will not need to declare this part.

So for you, look in your `RadTreeViewSampleData`.cs class file:

```
namespace ????????? // <<< What you have here is what you need to use
{
    public class RadTreeViewSampleData
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

So what XML namespace have you defined for your `sampleData` prefix in the control definition at the top of the XAML file where you have this XAML: `<sampleData:WpfTest x:Key="someDataSource"/>`? It should be something like this:

```
xmlns:sampleData="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
```

And you should use the name of the class that you want to use after the prefix, not the namespace:

```
<sampleData:RadTreeViewSampleData x:Key="someDataSource" />
```

Please take a look at the [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) page on MSDN for more information on XML namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sheridian. In my case my namespace is WpfTest and the project name is also WPfTest and i am still getting the error saying prefix sampleData is not defined. i am using this now <Window.Resources>
      <sampleData:WpfTest x:Key="someDataSource"/>
  </Window.Resources>

Comment: oh sorry i am rather getting this message  now. The type 'sampleData:WpfTest' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: That could be because `WpfTest` is not a class. I updated my answer for you... it sounds like you can just swap that for `RadTreeViewSampleData` and you could be alright now.

Comment: Yeap! thats it @Sheridian. its working now. Many thanks for your help and suggestions.Keep up the good work :)